# Is there any way to input a range of languages for the :lang() pseudo-class?

Tags: css, less, pseudo-class, code-cleanup

I'm targeting a bunch of different languages in my LESS/CSS with the [:lang() pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang). It looks like this (but even more languages):

```
:lang(af),
:lang(sq),
:lang(eu),
:lang(bs),
:lang(ca),
:lang(kw),
:lang(hr),
:lang(cs),
:lang(da),
:lang(nl) {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

Is there a way to clean this up? I'd love to enter in a list of languages somehow.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a set of languages for which you **don't** want font-size to be set to 100px? Is it any shorter?

Comment: Good question but there are multiple lists of languages that get different settings so that wouldn't help. Thanks